# Email Address validation using Python

Tags: python, email, smtp

I am using below  python code to check whether the entered Email address is valid or not.The code is hitting the SMTP server and giving correct response.Now i want to test 1000 Email and i fear the  SMTP server can block my IP.Can you please let me know what can i do to avoid this.

```
import re
import smtplib
import dns.resolver
# Address used for SMTP MAIL FROM command  
fromAddress = 'corn@bt.com'

# Simple Regex for syntax checking
regex = '^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,})$'

# Email address to verify
inputAddress = input('Please enter the emailAddress to verify:')
addressToVerify = str(inputAddress)

# Syntax check
match = re.match(regex, addressToVerify)
if match == None:
    print('Bad Syntax')
    raise ValueError('Bad Syntax')

# Get domain for DNS lookup
splitAddress = addressToVerify.split('@')
domain = str(splitAddress[1])
print('Domain:', domain)

# MX record lookup
records = dns.resolver.query(domain, 'MX')
mxRecord = records[0].exchange
mxRecord = str(mxRecord)


# SMTP lib setup (use debug level for full output)
server = smtplib.SMTP()
server.set_debuglevel(0)

# SMTP Conversation
server.connect(mxRecord)
server.helo(server.local_hostname) ### server.local_hostname(Get local server hostname)
server.mail(fromAddress)
code, message = server.rcpt(str(addressToVerify))
server.quit()

#print(code)
#print(message)

# Assume SMTP response 250 is success
if code == 250:
    print('Success')
else:
    print('Bad')
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Should this code run without any adjustment? I copied it, changed the "fromAddress" and gave it a run, but the only thing I see is a small CMD popup which quickly disappears, but no output is generated. Do I need to adjust the "server.local_hostname"?

Answer (score 0):

You can torrify your shell so that it change your IP every time when you are blocked.

Install OpenVPN on your Linux.

Comment: i will host the code in aws cloud